# Why does a dictionary change when not edited?

Tags: python, trie

I do not understand how `current = trie` (line 2) behaves.
How it is assigning and appending the new values?

```py
trie = {}
current = trie
word = "hello"
for ch in word:

    if ch not in current:
        current[ch] = {}

    current = current[ch]

current['*'] = True

print(trie)
print (current)
```

which gives as output:

```
{'h': {'e': {'l': {'l': {'o': {'*': True}}}}}}

{'*': True}
```

However I was expecting the value of `trie` not to change.

```py
b = 6 
a = b
a += 1 
print (a, b)
```

gives 7 6. Why b still pointing to 6?

Comment: Please explain how the actual behaviour does not meet your expectations (give example of what you expect, and what you actually get).

Comment: current and trie in that line are names referring to the same underlying dict object. mutations using one reference will reflect across all references. heres a [good read](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). They reuse the same technique later to further mutate contents in the line `current = current[ch]`. Now changes to `current` will reflect across `trie[ch]`

Comment: kindly add the expected input/output & objective of the above code.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh thanks. `b = 6
a = b

a += 1
print (a, b)` gives 7 6. Why b still pointing to 6? What is the difference in the question I asked and this one

Comment: @Atarnew the difference is one of mutation vs assignment. `list1[2] = 5` only modifies one "slot" of the same list container. So, even though it is an assignment, is it the kind of assignment that "mutates" something. however, when you write `a += 1` which roughly translates to `a = a + 1` the name "a" is being rebounded to a completely new object. (an int to be specific, with the value 7). Make sure you read the link too

Answer (score 0):

the variable you created (trie) is a dictionary. This data type is what is known as mutable which is where when the variable is copied exactly, the changing of one variable changes another because they both refer to the same place in memory. To stop this, you should use this code

```
import copy
trie = {}
current = copy.deepcopy(trie)
word = "hello"
for ch in word:

    if ch not in current:
        current[ch] = {}

    current = current[ch]

current['*'] = True
```